# webkit-box-reflect bug on android

Tags: android, css, reflection, webkit

I'm trying to add reflection on a mobile webview application (android and ios : so webkit only). I implemented a webkit-box-reflect like I saw on pretty good sites including stackoverflow.

```
"-webkit-box-reflect: below -14px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(white));"
```

I obtain that on android
[image: android behaviour]

And something like that on all others webkit 
[image: chrome behaviour]

As you can see on the android, there is no reflexion as it is not masked but it just put the gradient on the refected image. (seems to be a mask bug on webkit mobile). I could easily put another color than white (green) and inverse the orientation, but I need an image behind and not a plain background.

Do someone have an idea? all sites I saw don't mention android  or just show their work on plain background...

Answer (score 3):

The Android browser doesn't support webkit gradients as masks on box-reflects. As Ali.MD noted, you can use PNG images for the masks.

To avoid adding another HTTP request, you can also convert the PNG to a Data URI with something like http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/:

```
img {
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 
  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAyCAYAAACUEBHwAAAAIklEQVQ4jWP8//8/AzpgwhAZFRwVHBUctIIsDAwMXFQWBAAW4QORoT0UUQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Transparent Image for Mask

-webkit-box-reflect:below 0px url('image.png');

it work for me in android 2.3